# Automatically open headline on internal link

Tags: org-link

The following example implements an internal link to a headline:

```
* Heading1
- Important facts
* Heading2
- Jump to [[*Heading1][Link]]
```

When following/opening the "Link" with <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>, point moves to "Heading1". If the headline is closed, I would like it to open (unfold, expand) automatically when point lands. If the headline is already open, then do nothing (meaning, `org-cycle` can't be used).

Comment: You can use `org-show-subtree`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
(defun sw-org-unfold-headline-maybe ()
  (when (eq (car (org-element-at-point)) 'headline)
    (org-show-subtree)))

(add-hook 'org-follow-link-hook #'sw-org-unfold-headline-maybe)
```

The hook runs the function after the link has been followed and the function checks that it's at a headline before it unfolds it. There may be some spurious headline unfoldings though: I doubt that the function is selective enough as is.